# Adminlte div toggle to hide horizontal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using AdminLte Template for my Codeigniter system.
Is there anyway to change the hide and show to Horizontal instead of Vertical?

[image]

When i click the "Collapse", it hide Vertical way. I wanted to change it to "Horizontal" which like the menu bar, when i click "Collapse" it will hide to the left.

Here my current code for the Collapse button :

```
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm pull-right" data-widget="collapse"
                    data-toggle="tooltip" title="Collapse" style="margin-right: 5px;">
              <i class="fa fa-minus"></i></button>
```

Comment: use the docs of AdminLte to customize the behavior if possible

Comment: @DohaHelmy i don't find any about this

Comment: Maybe this example is useful: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_collapse_sidebar.asp